# Is Dispatcher-servlet in Spring MVC - Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

If `Dispatcher-Servlet` is not the controller then who is?

Controller is the one who manages the request and by this definition, it should be the controller.

What is the Model and View in this case?

Comment: The View is whatever framework you have on your front-end. It's what supposed to talk to the C (controller). The model is the underlaying data (domain) structure of your application.

Comment: So If I have Rest API with Spring MVC , we have multiple controllers for each request url, what are those ? are those not the controller ? and view is the JSON i am sending back in response ? domain is the model ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DispatcherServlet follows the Front Controller design pattern. The C in MVC refers to the page controller which retreives the data from the model (your services) and passes it to the view for rendering.

The purpose of the DispatcherServlet is to determine the page controller that is supposed to handle the request and coordinates the model and the view

Its an advanced servlet which can handle request mapping , locale resolution , view resolution , content negotiation etc